# Running a Sinatra server when non-root user

Tags: ruby, linux, unix, sinatra, server

I am part of a shared linux server, which is hosted on DigitalOcean.
I want to run a Sinatra web server from it, but I am not a `root` user. 
I set the port for 4040, with `set :port, 4040` and the server starts successfully with `ruby server.rb`.

```
== Sinatra/1.4.5 has taken the stage on 4040 for development with backup from WEBrick
[] INFO  WEBrick::HTTPServer#start: pid=18955 port=4040
```

When I visit the IP address like `http://IP_ADDRESS:4040`, nothing shows up.
**What am I doing wrong?**

Comment: What do you mean nothing shows up? Are you getting just a white page? If so, it means something is being served. What are you responding with through Sinatra?

Comment: @Brennan by nothing shows up, it gives me an 404 error page. In the sense, that the server is running on the port.

Comment: Did you try the basic hello world example from the docs? It should work. You don't need to be root to do that. Even production servers are not run as root. If you want to serve via port 80 you can later add nginx or apache to serve that port. But what I'm saying is that your mistake is elsewhere.